# Segmentation fault ('core' created) RPC - client doesn't execute

Tags: client-server, rpc

Hope you can help me on this. 
I have been trying to find out where my error is almost all day. This is RPC. Client has to ask Server which IP belongs to a host. That's all.
Server works ok, but when I try to execute Client side, I received notification that I had an issue with "Segmentation fault, ('core') generated".

Here's my ips.x file:

```
struct envia
{
  char dominio[50];
};

struct retorno
{
  char retips[50];
};

program IPS_PROGRAMA
{
  version VERSION_IPS_PROGRAMA
  {
    struct retorno ips (struct envia) =1;
   } =1;
}=0x20000001;
```

Here's the ips_client.c:

```
/*
 * This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
 * These are only templates and you can use them
 * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include "ips.h"


 void
ips_programa_1(char *host,char *dominio)
{
  CLIENT *clnt;
  struct retorno  *result_1;
  struct envia  ips_1_arg;

#ifndef DEBUG

clnt = clnt_create (host, IPS_PROGRAMA, VERSION_IPS_PROGRAMA, "udp");

if (clnt == NULL) {
    clnt_pcreateerror (host);
    exit (1);
}
#endif  /* DEBUG */

  strcpy(ips_1_arg.dominio,dominio);

  result_1 = ips_1(&ips_1_arg, clnt);

  if (result_1 == (struct retorno *) NULL) {
    clnt_perror (clnt, "call failed");
   }
    printf("recibido del servidor %s \n", result_1->retips);
 #ifndef    DEBUG
  clnt_destroy (clnt);
 #endif  /* DEBUG */
 }


 int
 main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *host;

   if (argc < 2) {
    printf ("usage: %s server_host\n", argv[0]);
    exit (1);
 }
host = argv[1];
ips_programa_1 (host,argv[2]);
exit (0);
}
```

And here's my ips.server.c:

```
/*
 * This is sample code generated by rpcgen.
 * These are only templates and you can use them
 * as a guideline for developing your own functions.
 */

#include "ips.h"
#include<netdb.h>  
#include<string.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>


void funcionip(char * ,char []);

struct retorno *
ips_1_svc(struct envia *argp, struct svc_req *rqstp)
{
  static struct retorno  result;

  memset(result.retips,0,100);
  funcionip(argp->dominio,result.retips);

  return &result;
}

void funcionip(char * dominio, char TodasLasIp[])
{
   struct in_addr **addr_list;
   struct hostent *he = gethostbyname(dominio);

   if (he)
   { 
     int i;
     puts(he->h_name);
     printf("Servidor Dice Nombre del Host : %s\n", he->h_name);
     printf("Servidor Dice Direcciones IP  ");
     addr_list = (struct in_addr **)he->h_addr_list;

     for(i = 0; addr_list[i] != NULL; i++)
       {
         printf("%s \n", inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
         strcat(TodasLasIp,(char*) inet_ntoa(*addr_list[i]));
         strcat(TodasLasIp,"\n");
       }
      printf("\n");
    }
else
  {       
    printf("Servidor dice error gethostbyname\n");
    strcat(TodasLasIp,"error gethostbyname\n");
  }   
}
```

I have worked in other RPC where struct defined in ".x" file where just integer. So I think error is something about data types?

Any help is really appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Also, when compiling ips_client.c I have this error:
     `tmp/cc6nxH9t.o : In function 'ips_programa_1':
      ips_client.c: (.text+0x83): undefined reference to 'ips_1'
      collect2: ld returned exit status (1)`

Answer (score 0):

I have found my stupid error!!!
When executing ips_client, I'm being required 3 THREE arguments:
argv[0], argv[1] and argv[2].
But, I'm so silly that just forget the last one.. ¬¬

Sorry!!! hehe